# how to install Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I installed Mit-gnu scheme on my machine but am unable to make it work?
Can someone help? I am new to programming and am excited to learn scheme. Thanks.
my machine config: windows, 32 bit, xp professional.

Comment: This is totally inadequate information.  What precisely did you get, what did you do with it, and what do you mean by "unable to make it work"?  What errors do you get?

Comment: i was trying out the first example from "The Little Schemer" 
which is found on page xii: define "atom?" and then check if 
this is correct. here's the code: 
(define atom?
 (lambda(x)
  (and (not(pair? x)) (not (null? x)))))
  
and when I typed
(atom? (quote()))

nothing happened.

Comment: i must add that I was trying this in edwin.

Comment: So you did get scheme running then?  Or how did you get edwin running (Wikipedia says it's an editor in that version of Scheme)?  The code looks correct.  What exactly did you type the code into, and exactly what happened?

Comment: @David: I typed the code in Edwin and nothing happened. When I typed the command to check if the atom? is defined correctly, nothing happened too. I was hoping that I would get a response back like in the python IDLE editor.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried typing `mit-scheme` in the shell?

The easiest way to get started with Scheme (as someone new to programming) is probably to install Racket:

http://racket-lang.org/

and follow their tutorials:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/quick/index.html

Comment: I have not tried typing 'mit-scheme' in the shell. How do you do that?

Comment: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos126/cmd-prompt.html

Comment: when I typed mit-shell, I got an error: 'mit-shell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: I said `mit-scheme` and you are typing `mit-shell`.

Comment: i typed 'mit-scheme'. The above is a typo. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If 'mit-scheme' isn't recognized, you need to update your PATH environment variable. But, as z5h said, Racket is probably the best way to get started - DrRacket is a very capable IDE, and the tutorials and documentation are excellent.

Comment: On Ubuntu you can run `sudo apt install mit-scheme`. And once installed, start it by writing `scheme` on the terminal.